# Handling complex arguments of elliptic integrals in Maple

Tags: calculus, special-functions, maple, elliptic-integrals

I want to solve the integral

\begin{equation}
I(y)=\int_0^y\sqrt{\dfrac{x(1+ax)}{(1+ax)^2-b^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x,\qquad a<0,\; b\in(0,1),\; y>0,\; (1+ax)^2-b^2>0,
\end{equation}

using Maple 18. The solution is known to be real. Maple finds a solution in terms of incomplete elliptic integrals of the first, second, and third kind:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{EllipticF}(z,k), \;\;\mathrm{EllipticE}(z,k), \;\;\mathrm{EllipticPi}(z,n,k).
\end{equation}

Although when evaluated numerically Maple gives indeed the correct answer, the arguments are:

\begin{equation}
z=\sqrt{\dfrac{-yab}{(1+ay)(1-b)}}, \quad k=\mathrm{i}\,\sqrt{\dfrac{b-1}{b+1}},\quad \mathrm{and}\quad n = \dfrac{1-b}{b},
\end{equation}

where $z,n\in\mathbb{R}$ but $k\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\Re(k)=0$, since $b\in(0,1)$. So there is one complex argument, $k$.

Is there any way to rearrange Maple's output to avoid dealing with complex arguments, provided that everything is known to be real? Maybe some simplifications?

If I study the case $b>1$ with the corresponding `assuming` the solution from Maple has the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i\,EllipticF}(z,k), \;\; \mathrm{i\,EllipticE}(z,k), \;\; \mathrm{i\,EllipticPi}(z,n,k).
\end{equation}
where now $k\in\mathbb{R}$. The elliptic integrals give purely imaginary values, but they are multiplied by $\mathrm{i}$. Again, would it be possible to simplify this somehow to avoid using complex numbers?

Comment: Almost certainly this is what you want: http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7#E5

Comment: Most CAS **suck** at producing useful elliptic integral expressions. You might want to look at Byrd/Friedman and see if your particular form is in there.

Comment: Thanks! Those transformations look like the answer, I'll try them. I will also take a look at Byrd/Friedman.