# Elliptic integrals of complex argument and parameter

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematica, elliptic-integrals

`Mathematica` has the annoying habit to provide solutions involving incomplete elliptic integrals of the first kind $E(z|m)$, second kind $F(z|m)$ and third kind $\Pi(n;z|m)$ where $z$, $m$ and $n$ are arbitrary complex numbers. However, some numerical interfaces only support classical definitions: $0<m<1$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}<z<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $n\in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, what is the simplest transformation formula to reach these easier-to-handle parameter and argument (or at least real values)?

I have consulted traditional formula lists such as P. F. Byrd et al., *Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists* but it has been surprisingly difficult to find a way to deal with complex $m$ (while the case of negative $m$ is widely covered). As such, this question differs from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844415/real-and-imaginary-parts-for-f-varphi-m-with-complex-argument) or this [other demand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263875/handling-complex-arguments-of-elliptic-integrals-in-maple).

Comment: JM's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659/21783) concerning conventions may help.

Comment: Right; $m$ is a parameter and not a modulus. I edited to dispel the possible confusion.